# binding unix user to mysql

Tags: mysql, unix, users

I am just asking myself if it is possible to bind unix users to mysql.
So that I can bind databases to users or groups known by unix.

Thx,
Axel

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean by binding. Do you want to make it possible to use mysql with pam?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pam-mysql/

Comment: I wanted that users, that log in via ssh for example, can access mysql with their unix login.
And the only thing I (as an admin) want to do is, creating the unix login for a user, the rest should be done automaticly.
But seems like PAM could be a help. I'll have a look at it.
Thx